# How to preserve unknown fields using protobuf-java-format

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

If I have a protobuf message with unknown fields:

```
leaf1: "Hello"
leaf2: 23
leaf3: 41
4: "world"
```

where leaf1, leaf2, and leaf3 are my known fields, and 4 is an unknown field.  I then convert to json using protobuf-java-format like so:

```
return new JsonFormat().printToString(protobuf);
```

I get the following:

`{"leaf1": "Hello","leaf2": 23,"leaf3": 41, "4": "world"}`

However, if I then deserialize the json back like so:

```
public static <T extends Message> T convertToProtobuf(String json, T defaultInstance)
    throws ParseException {
    Builder builder = defaultInstance.newBuilderForType();
    JsonFormat format = new JsonFormat();
    format.merge(json, ExtensionRegistry.getEmptyRegistry(), builder);
    return (T)builder.build();
}
```

then my result is the following:

```
leaf1: "Hello"
leaf2: 23
leaf3: 41
```

The problem is field 4 is not present in the reconstituted proto as an unknown field. Am I doing something wrong, or is this not supported? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with protobuf-java-format but FWIW it wouldn't surprise me at all if it simply doesn't support encoding unknown fields into JSON. It's kind of awkward because protobuf unknown fields are tightly coupled to the protobuf encoding, so encoding them in JSON is unintuitive. That said, IMO it would make sense for protobuf-json-format to be extended with the ability to do this somehow.

Comment: Thanks @Kenton. It looks like its an actual [bug](https://github.com/bivas/protobuf-java-format/issues/23).

Answer (score 0):

Setting unknown fields into the provided `Builder` is not supported by `JsonFormat` - it will just discard them and keep consuming the remaining JSON string.

Javadoc for `JsonFormat` at `protobuf-java-util`:

> Utility classes to convert protobuf messages to/from JSON format. The
>   JSON  format follows Proto3 JSON specification and only proto3
>   features are  supported. Proto2 only features (e.g., extensions and
>   unknown fields) will  be discarded in the conversion. That is, when
>   converting proto2 messages  to JSON format, extensions and unknown
>   fields will be treated as if they  do not exist. This applies to
>   proto2 messages embedded in proto3 messages  as well.